# Display today's sunrise/sunset at Easter Island

Tags: timezone, astronomy

I need to display today's sunrise and sunset at Easter Island in local Easter Island time. I'm implementing it to the sidebar at http://www.easterislandtraveling.com/easter-island/

I noticed the EarthTools (http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#sun) only covers Europe and USA. Is there any other way?

Over at http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?n=914 they have all the necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around some with the standard PHP functions date_sun_info(), date_sunrise() and date_sunset() but I couldn't get them to work well with the local timezone.

I found a website that offers the service I'm looking for: 
http://www.happyzebra.com/widgets/sunrisesunset.php?city=Easter%20Island

Works great! Only differed 2 minutes on the sunrise compared to http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=914